# multiprocessing kafka messages

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

we have one kafka consumer that is constantly polling kafka topic and processing messages.
we are facing issues how much value we should put for `max.poll.records`.
For processing each of this message we have 3 rest calls.
What I am doing is get messages as list and process using parallel stream.
Instance is having 2GB memory space and `max.poll.records` is 8.
So, now if I increase `max.poll.records` then message processing time increases and it best performs when `max.poll.records` is 4.
Could you please shed some light how we can increase parallel processing of messages using 1 instance using 1 partition that means instead of fetching 
8 messages, what else can I try to make it process around 5 messages.

Update:-
Below is memory configuraion, I am deploying standalone app in pcf.

JVM Memory Configuration:

```
-Xmx1422566K -Xss1M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=162585K
```

Comment: Your question is not much clear. What do you want to achieve and what do you mean by **parallel processing**? In Kafka, the level of parallelism is facilitated through partitions and multiple consumer instances.

Comment: I mean to say, I want to fetch around 20 messages from kafka and process them in parallel. Just assume I have one consumer and only one partition. So, I want to increase max.poll.records and without compromising overall message process time.

Answer (score 0):

`max.poll.records` does not affect the level of parallelism. According to the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs),

> `max.poll.records`: The maximum number of records returned in a single
>   call to poll().

If you increase the value of this configuration, you will be able to fetch more records at each poll but it doesn't mean that you are going to process the messages in parallel.

The level of parallelism in Kafka is controlled by the number of partitions and the number of consumer instances which are up and running.

A Kafka topic is divided into a number of partitions which enables parallelism by splitting the data across multiple brokers. Multiple partitions enable multiple consumers to read from a topic in parallel. Therefore, in order to achieve parallel processing you need to partition your topic into more than one partitions.

In order to increase the number of partitions of an existing topic you can simply run

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic topicName --partitions 10
```

*This won't move existing data, though*

**Note on consumers, consumer groups and partitions**
 
If you have N partitions, then you can have up to N consumers within the same consumer group each of which reading from a single partition. When you have less consumers than partitions, then some of the consumers will read from more than one partition. Also, if you have more consumers than partitions then some of the consumers will be inactive and will receive no messages at all from those instances.

Comment: thanks, got it. Would you be able to help me for problem:- I have 5000 messages in topic and I am fetching 8 records and processing them, so to process total 5k records it takes around 63 seconds.
I want to fetch more records and some how reduce the processing time. so, what can be strategies for this. This way I can also reduce poll trips to the broker.

Comment: @RahulSingh What you'd need to do is to increase the number of partitions for your topic (e.g. set it to 3), and then start 3 Kafka Consumers that belong to the _same_ consumer-group.

Comment: sounds good, but I am looking forward to optimize at java end some how, to poll more records and process them. Anyideas ?

Comment: @RahulSingh if you want to process more records per poll then simply increase `max.poll.records`.

Comment: yeah, that I did but, it is having performance hit, then it takes more time to process 5k messages, nit sure why this behavior.

Comment: Can I have call with you to discuss  may be skype or hangout.?

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to **Giorgos** answer, this clarifications comes from [Kafka the definitive guide](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/)

There are several factors to consider when choosing the number of
partitions:

> - What is the throughput you expect to achieve for the topic? For example, do you expect to write 100 KB per second or 1 GB per second?
> - What is the maximum throughput you expect to achieve when consuming from a single partition? You will always have, at most, one consumer
>     reading from a partition, so if you know that your slower consumer
>     writes the data to a database and this database never handles more
>     than 50 MB per second from each thread writing to it, then you know
>     you are limited to 60MB throughput when consuming from a partition.
> - You can go through the same exercise to estimate the maximum throughput per producer for a single partition, but since producers
>     are typically much faster than consumers, it is usu‐ ally safe to skip
>     this.
> - If you are sending messages to partitions based on keys, adding partitions later can be very challenging, so calculate throughput
>     based on your expected future usage, not the current usage.
> - Consider the number of partitions you will place on each broker and available diskspace and network bandwidth per broker.
> - Avoid overestimating, as each partition uses memory and other resources on the broker and will increase the time for leader
>     elections.
>
> With all this in mind, it’s clear that you want many partitions but
>   not too many.
>
> If you have some estimate regarding the target
>   throughput of the topic and the expected throughput of the consumers, you can divide 
>   the target throughput by the expected consumer throughput and derive the number of  partitions this way. So if I
>   want to be able to write and read 1 GB/sec from a topic, and I know
>   each consumer can only process 50 MB/s, then I know I need at least 20
>   partitions. This way, I can have 20 consumers reading from the topic
>   and achieve 1 GB/sec. If you don’t have this detailed information, our
>   experience suggests that limiting the size of the partition on the
>   disk to less than 6 GB per day of retention often gives satisfactory
>   results.